# How to build unique array of objects with condition in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have an array of objects and want to build an unique array by the attribute "position", like

```
boxes.to_a.uniq! {|p| p[:position] }
```

but i want to distinguish before throwing all the doubles away, if the second attribute "mismatch" is equal or higher. For example i have:

```
{ position: 233, mismatch: 3},
{ position: 234, mismatch: 3},
{ position: 233, mismatch: 1}
```

and in the end i'd like to keep the one with less mismatch:

```
{ position: 234, mismatch: 3},
{ position: 233, mismatch: 1}
```

because position was the same in object 1 and 3, but mismatch was less in the last object.

Edit: boxes is an array of objects and i build it like that:

```
@boxes = []

...

@boxes << {
              :position => i,
              :mismatch => mm,
          }
```

where position and mismatch is calculated over a DNA sequence. The mismatch represents the hamming distance to a 9-nucleotide motif ( string like "TTGATGCTT" )

Comment: What is `boxes` originally?  Hashes can't have duplicate keys anyways, so this is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what these hashes represent, so you can probably think of better variable names.

Try:

```
boxes = [
  { position: 233, mismatch: 3},
  { position: 234, mismatch: 3},
  { position: 233, mismatch: 1},
]

boxes.group_by{ |box| box[:position] }
     .map{ |_, boxes| boxes.min_by{ |box| box[:mismatch] } }
#=> [{:position=>233, :mismatch=>1}, {:position=>234, :mismatch=>3}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
new_boxes = {}

boxes.each do |box|
  pos = box[:position]
  if new_boxes[pos] && new_boxes[pos][:mismatch] > box[:mismatch]
    new_boxes[pos] = box
  end
end

boxes = new_boxes.values
```

Answer (score 0):

```
boxes = [
  { position: 233, mismatch: 1},
  { position: 234, mismatch: 3},
  { position: 233, mismatch: 3},
  { position: 234, mismatch: 2}
]

boxes.sort_by{|x| x.values }
     .uniq{|y| y[:position]}

#=> [{:position=>233, :mismatch=>1}, {:position=>234, :mismatch=>2}]
```